# How does ${aapt} get defined? (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, ant, android-ndk

Recently I've been trying to build an Android NDK application that in the past has compiled and packaged without issue. But something has changed either as a result of a system update or an SDK update, and now when I try to build the application I get the following error:

`/home/kazade/Android/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:649: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/kazade/Android/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:694: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/kazade/Git/wizards/android/${aapt}": error=2, No such file or directory`

I've checked, and aapt is available on the PATH. In the build.xml that comes with the SDK the task is just defined as:

`<aapt executable="${aapt}"`

So presumably the location of aapt is supposed to be stored in that environment variable? I'm guessing it's not and that's what's causing the problem, but I can't figure out why it's not defined, or where it should be.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it's a bug in the SDK: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176488